# google cloud sql -- mysql import issue

Tags: mysql, import, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to import a table in a newly created instance in google MySQL cloud but I get the following error message:

`Error 1142: INSERT command denied to user 'cloudsqlimport'@'127.0.0.1' for table`

When I try to grant the privileges to cloudsqlimport from cloud sql console:

```
mysql> UPDATE `mysql`.`user` SET `insert_priv` = 'Y' WHERE `User` = 'cloudsqlimport';
ERROR 1142 (42000): UPDATE command denied to user 'root'@'104.xxx.xx.xx' for table 'user'

mysql> UPDATE `mysql`.`user` SET `Grant_priv` = 'Y' WHERE `User` = 'root';
ERROR 1142 (42000): UPDATE command denied to user 'root'@'104.xxx.xx.xx' for table 'user'
```

Same issue when I try to grant the 'insert_priv' through MySQL workbench

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: you wouldn't get much help in such issues as Cloud SQL includes a lot of internal work and the best way to get assistance in your case in to contact support by following this https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases

Answer (score 1):

This error might be due to one of the following causes:

1- Lack of permissions

2- Database or Table spelled wrongly.

3- User correctly spelled but the IP is not correct.

To see the permissions your user has, Please log into MySQL prompt with your user, and run the following command:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

This will show you the privileges ([grants](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html) in MySQL) that the current user has. Please check if you have INSERT privileges for the given table.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when importing a dump of `mysql.user` table.
Even thought it is not exactly what your issue is, still it might be relevant, so let me share what a GCP engineer suggestion was.
There are two options:

1. Use now deprecated `mysqlpump` instead of `mysqdump` when getting a dump from a table with `--users`  flag
2. Use MariaDB version of mysqldump with the `--system` flag to create the dump including `CREATE USER` commands

A `mysql.user` table dump taken with one of those options can be successfully imported using `gcloud sql import sql` command.